# Will a Steam account work across platforms?

Tags: steam

I have never used Steam before, but now I want to install Steam because there are some games that are having a Cyber Monday sale today.  The problem is that my Windows PC is broken at the moment, so I would have to install Steam on my Mac.

If I create a Steam account with my Mac, could I then later use the same account if I install Steam onto a Windows PC?

Comment: If you just want to buy games, you can also do so via a browser. You don't need to install Steam on your Mac, if you don't want to. However, whenever you use Steam over a new platform/browser, you will have to first input a code which will be sent to you via mail. This is meant to make life harder on hackers.

Comment: It does, however, allow you to install it without hassle and start playing any game that is compatable with your Mac.

Comment: More and more games work on Linux, too

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The same Steam account will work on all platforms. Most games don't work on both Mac and Windows, though, so bear that in mind. You can find out the compatible platforms for each game on their Store page, at the bottom with system requirements. Steam should still always let you buy any game (available in your region) for any platform.

Comment: But regardless of system requirements, you can buy any game on a Mac computer.  You just can't install it unless there is a Mac version available.

Comment: @JasonBerkan Let me add this because I don't know the answer but it seems very relevant to the question - if a game DOES have Mac compatability (Say, Team Fortress 2), will owning a copy of the game allow him to install it on his Mac regardless of what system he originally bought it on?

Comment: @Zibbobz - Yes.  Your Steam account cares not for your OS, provided the OS X and Windows versions are not actually separate game entries in Steam.

Comment: Are there games where the OSX, Windows, or Linux versions are in fact separate entries in Steam?

Comment: @BrianMinton The great majority of games are the same entry (which Steam calls SteamPlay - see https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=9439-QHKN-1308). Doing a quick search, the only game I could find with a separate entry for Mac was Call of Duty Black Ops. Searching for Mac games shows 596 titles http://store.steampowered.com/search/?os=mac&category1=998 while searching for SteamPlay games comes up with 595 but there are some SteamPlay games without Mac support, so that leaves a few unaccounted for.

Comment: GTAs also have separate entries for Mac and PC.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, you can !**

You will be able to connect to steam even from your phone, but some games may not work for mac and some may not work for pc, but you can still buy games for windows from a mac and games for mac from windows.